# Is there any Chrome extension (or combination) providing the same features as Firebug?

Tags: firebug, google-chrome

I searched a while and found no extension that can compete with Firebug. Perhaps combination of several extensions can provide similar feature set of Firebug.

Anybody develop web app and unit test mainly in Chrome can share some knowledge?

Comment: what do you need in relation to unit test? Selenium allows you to build tests that can run on with browser

Comment: For example, with "Inspect Element", I can only navigate in HTML code. I'k like to click on web page and related HTML element get highlighted, just like in Firebug.

Comment: That highlight feature is in the built-in dev tools in Chrome.

Comment: To make the page clickable so that the related HTML is highlighted, go to the dev tools dialog, choose the "elements" tab, click on the little magnifying glass icon at the bottom of the dialog, then click on your HTML element of choice.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J on Windows)? They're actually pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Chrome developer tools are pretty good.  What else are you specifically looking for?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cqh7MGLgaM

Answer (score 2):

The [Developer Tools](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html) covers most of Firebug's functionality, and [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) is an extension you want to have to complement that (that's out of Firebug's scope).  If you're used to Firebug and slow to pick up new interfaces, there is always the [Firebug bookmarklet](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firebug Lite extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench